# How to place the text to center of the layout if image is in left side of the layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

In the Relative layout I used an image in left side of the layout and textview should be the right of the image and  I need the textview should be the center of Reltaive layout. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

code:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.z003tcnc.myapplication.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: I need an output like this]

Comment: can you share a picture of layout you need??

Comment: I have shared image too

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to TextView if you want textview tocenter of relative layout.

```
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is how it would look like

[image]

and if you need you could put this into a

Comment: no actually i want the textview should be the center of Linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

set the margin accoring to your need..

```
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image's height is bigger than that of the text view.

Use `alignTop` & `alignBottom` on the TextView so that it covers the same height as the image. Then center the text in the TextView using `android:gravity="center"`

**EDIT:: ADDED CODE TO CENTER BOTH VIEWS IN THE RELATIVE LAYOUT**

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE: I have tested the xml layout & IT WORKS**

Comment: Can you check my updated image.I want exactly like that

Comment: So now to make both the `imageVIew` & `TextView` at the vertical center of the layout, Add `android:gravity="center"` to the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Change only two line:
Make Parent relative layout height as wrap content and add CenterVertical true in TextView,set some margin from left according to your need.

Here is code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwkm8.png
```

Comment: I want the textview center horizontally

Comment: then only remove this android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1" , i checked and updated the code

Comment: If I remove text will overlap with the image

Comment: ya I tried there are chances of having long text in the textview.That time text will overlap with the image if I dont give android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"

Comment: put margin from left then  no chance of overlapping and upvote the answer dude

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of using two separate components use this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

Change parameters according to your need.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from your TextView:

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```